# Formulario de Consentimiento Uso de Datos Personales para Publicidad

Tags: admob

Estoy intentando configurar el formulario para recoger el consentimiento del usuario para la publicidad según las directrices de esta página: https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start.

El tipo de formulario que estoy implementando es el de dos botones y me he dado cuenta de que, independientemente del botón pulsado, el status es siempre 3 o lo que es lo mismo:

```
consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED
```

pero únicamente se muestra publicidad si el botón pulsado es 'Consentir'.

Dejo imágenes para que se entienda mejor:
[image: Imagenes dialogo consensentimiento publicidad]

Por otro lado, al final de esa misma página, hay un código para solicitar publicidad no personalizada.

Cómo se sabe si el usuario a dado o no el permiso para usar sus datos o si permite la publicidad personalizada o no porque el único dato que se puede obtener es el de ConsentInformation y el valor es siempre el mismo, aunque el comportamiento o respuesta no lo sea.

Si sabéis algo más de lo que explican en esa página os ruego que lo compartáis. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que preguntas

> Cómo se sabe si el usuario a dado o no el permiso para usar sus datos
> o si permite la publicidad personalizada o no porque el único dato que
> se puede obtener es el de ConsentInformation y el valor es siempre el
> mismo, aunque el comportamiento o respuesta no lo sea?

Lo que realizas aquì es verificar que se el consentimiento fue obtenido,

```
function loadFormSuccessHandler( event:UserMessagingPlatformEvent ):void
{  
    if (Adverts.service.ump.getConsentInformation().getConsentStatus() == ConsentStatus.OBTAINED)
    {
        Adverts.service.ump.showConsentForm();
    }
}
```

**siempre obtienes el valor 3 (ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) lo cual indica que el consentimiento del usuario fue obtenido.**

Actualmente muchos de los permisos son definidos por el criterio del usuario, no hay forma de forzar a que el usuario tenga que aceptar un permiso.

Comment: Gracias por contestar. No pretendo obligar al usuario a que dé ningún permiso pero si pretendo tomar medidas en caso de que no quiera publicidad, por ejemplo, como se hacía en el anterior Consent SDK, ofrecerle la posibilidad de comprar la versión sin publicidad. Por otro lado, el capítulo de la página que indico 'Forward consent to the Google Mobile Ads SDK' no tiene sentido si no hay alguna forma de controlar si el usuario seleccionó publicidad personalizada o no personalizada.